# Finde positive and negative numbers from Array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have one Assignment and I need help .
int[] array={12,23,-22,043,545,-4,-55,43,12,0,-99,-87}
and I must  make two array. first for positive , second for negative and  duplicate nubers . I can not use ArrayList.

int[] array={12,23,-22,0,43,545,-4,-55,43,12,0,-999,-87};

```
       for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){   
          if(array[i]>0){
              System.out.println("Positive:"+array[i]);               
          }
          else if 
               (array[i]<0){
               System.out.println("Negative:"+array[i]);   
           }
           for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] ==array[i]) {
                 System.out.println("Dup:"+array[j]);

    }

}
       }
}
```

RES IS:run:
Postive:12
Dupli:12
Postive:23
Negative:-22
Dupli:0
Postive:43
Dupli:43
Postive:545
Negative:-4
Negative:-55
Postive:43
Postive:12
Negative:-999
Negative:-87
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
 But i don know 
how do I get this Postive: 12,23,0,43,545, etc.

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Show what u have tried ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it´s a assignment dump without showing any effort to solve it.

Comment: Use `for` to loop over the arrays and `if` to check conditions. There you go, now implement a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to understand the code and answer your professor,

```
 int[] array={12,23,-22,043,545,-4,-55,43,12,0,-99,-87};
   List<Integer> postiveNumbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> negativeNumbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> duplicateNumbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(!(postiveNumbers.contains(array[i])||negativeNumbers.contains(array[i]))) {//checks whether it contains duplicates

            if (array[i] >= 0) {
                postiveNumbers.add(array[i]);
            } else if (array[i] < 0) {
                negativeNumbers.add(array[i]);
            }
        }
        else duplicateNumbers.add(array[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(postiveNumbers);
    System.out.println(negativeNumbers);
    System.out.println(duplicateNumbers);
```

Comment: thx guys  for help ...

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public void test() {
    int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 043, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -99, -87};
    List<Integer> positive = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> negative = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> duplicate = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int n = array[i];
        // Simple check for +ve/-ve
        if (n >= 0) {
            positive.add(n);
        } else {
            negative.add(n);
        }
        // Check for duplicates.
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] == n) {
                duplicate.add(n);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("+ve - " + positive);
    System.out.println("-ve - " + negative);
    System.out.println("dup - " + duplicate);
}
```

Please remember that your professor has full and open access to this answer and may even have an account her at SO. Please be sure to fully understand this code or you will not learn this part of your course.

Comment: oky ,  I konw that , but i can t use List , ArrayList ... only for and if

Comment: With this algorithm, if you have N occurrences of the same number, it will be stored multiple times in the "duplicate" list, actually N(N-1)/2 times. I guess this is not what we need.

Comment: @Ira - You could use arrays instead of the `List`s but that would be more complicated. You might find using a `StringBuilder` or even append to a `String` if you must.

Comment: @KonstantinosChalkias - Good point - if this is a problem then a `Set` would be more appropriate for the duplicates.

Comment: thx people for help ....

Comment: A Set will work for unique elements, but even if we wanted to store each occurrence, current solution needs to be fixed. Imagine that you have an array like {5,5,5,5}; your approach will create a duplicate list with six 5s {5,5,5,5,5,5}. Your "check for duplicates" block should change